# Why does a p tag with a margin not stay within a containing div?

Tags: html, css

This is probably a simple question but why in the following does the paragraph tag (including margin) not stay within its containing div?

```
<div class="blockone"></div>
<div>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>

.blockone {
    background-color:Red;
    height:100px;
    margin:50px 0px;
}
div p {
    margin:50px 0px;
}
```

Have put the example in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dr6kN/7/

What I would expect would be that the text and block were 100px apart? I know I get this behaviour by floating, and can bodge to make work but am seeking a bit of understanding :)

Comment: Which div are you referring to as the "containing div"?

Comment: the second one (containing the paragraph tag)

Comment: The fiddle shows that it *is* inside the second one...

Comment: but it's margin isn't? (maybe badly worded the question)

Comment: Confusing question. @BoltClock you should undelete your answer, it's close enough. He's certainly talking about margin collapsing in some form.

Comment: How do you want the margins? In your example you have margin top and bottom of 50px, and margin left and right 0px, and it is place ok in fiddle...

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but the *first* thing I always do is to slap style='border:solid 1px red;' (and other colors) on my elements to see clearer what's going on. You also need to specify if this is particular browsers, as the whole IE family have margin hangups (and more).

Comment: have tested in firefox / chrome . I think BoltClock has answered my question, never knew about collapsing margins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're referring to as the "containing div", because the `p` is in the *second* `div` (the bottom, transparent one), so it technically *is* in its containing `div`.

> What I would expect would be that the text and block were 100px apart?

Due to [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), the `p`'s margin collapses into the red `div`'s margin, so only the red `div`'s 50-pixel margin takes apparent effect.

Comment: ok, had never heard of collapsing margins. It seems then that I can get the desired gap by adding 'display:inline-block;' to div p

Comment: @Tim: A "better" way to "fix" it is to add `overflow: hidden` to the containing `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/dr6kN/12/